# Building (delayed prices) trading system using google finance API or yahoo finance API

Tags: c#, java, finance, google-finance, yahoo-finance

Im interested in using one of the two named APIs for building my own hobby-project trading system. My question is, i would prefer to build this in Java, C++ or C#. Is this possible considering the type of APIs yahoo and google offer? I had the impression i'd have to write a web page or something.

Comment: Do you mean that you want to create a desktop application and not a web application?

Answer (score 1):

From the point of view of the API provider, there is no difference between a web site and a desktop application. So, yeah, it's possible, you don't have to have a website.

On the other hand, your question seems to indicate that you can't build a website using the languages you mention, which is simply not true. You could use ASP.NET or JSP to create a website using C# or Java if you wanted.